# CSS Unable to animate a board?

Tags: html, css

I have made a tic tac toe board and trying to produce some kind of glow effect. But when I animate using keyframes the side that I removed are also being displayed and also the animation is non uniform.

```
td{
    width:115px;
    height:115px;
    border: 4px solid rgba(0, 191, 255,0.3); 
    animation: borderGlow 1s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
}
table{
    border-collapse: collapse;
    position: absolute;
    top:25%;
}
table tr:first-child td{
    border-top:none;
}
table tr:last-child td{
    border-bottom:none;
}
table tr td:first-child{
    border-left:none;
}
table tr td:last-child{
    border-right:none;
}

@keyframes borderGlow{
    from{
        border: 4px solid rgba(0, 191, 255,0.3);  
    }
    to{
        border: 4px solid rgba(0, 191, 255,1);
    }
}

<table>
            <tr>
                <td class="cell" id="0">O</td>
                <td class="cell" id="1">X</td>
                <td class="cell-2" id="2">O</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="cell-2" id="3">O</td>
                <td class="cell-2" id="4">O</td>
                <td class="cell" id="5">X</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="cell" id="6">X</td>
                <td class="cell" id="7">O</td>
                <td class="cell" id="8">X</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

Comment: what you mean by 'the side that I removed'

Comment: if u want to remove animation from the <td> with no border, please add 'animation:none' to the css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to specify all of the border's attributes for the animation (as you are overwriting your `none` values by that), just the color would suffice:

```
@keyframes borderGlow {
    from {
        border-color: rgba(0, 191, 255, 0.3);  
    }
    to {
        border-color: rgba(0, 191, 255, 1);
    }
}
```

Also, the animation seems pretty "uniform" by my side. Perhaps, you could play with easing in order to achieve a more linear effect.